# Backbone.js: create or update pattern, post save pattern

Tags: backbone.js

I'm wondering if there's a common pattern for either saving (POST) or updating (PUT) a model depending on if an instance of that model already exists.  I found myself doing something like this in my code

```
var UserProfileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/v1/userprofile'
});

function upsave(){
    var userprofile = new UserProfileModel({ 
        user: self.user_id, 
        user_type:  self.user_type, 
        userprofile_complete: true
    });

    userprofile.fetch({
        success: function(model, response, options) {
            //model exists and is now populated
            userprofile.set('user_type', self.user_type);
            userprofile.set('userprofile_complete', true);
            userprofile.save();
        },

        error: function(model, xhr, options) {
            if(xhr.status === 404) {
                //model was not found
                userprofile.save();
            } 
            else {
                alert('The server encountered an error saving the user profiile');
                console.log(xhr.status);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I get the model attributes from places, create a new model, fetch the model, if it exists use the set attribute, if it returns 404, save.  Is this an acceptable design pattern?  I'm new to backbone and wondering if this is the  proper way to handle it.

And also, after a successful save event, what's the right way to send a user to the next uri?  I know you can do: `document.location.href = '/some/relative/url/'` and that works, but I come from a django background where redirects are handled in the views and I'm not hardcoding URL's into templates.  I'd like to not get back to doing that.

Comment: Backbone (Sync) will do this automatically for you, depending on wether a model already has an "id" attribute, thus being existant on the server or not. So, just call `model.save()`- it will post a new model and put an existing model. Don't forgat to return the whole model from the server upon saving it.

Comment: That's what I initially thought as well, but without first fetching the save() function automatically generates a POST without the `id` in it.  Which causes and error 500 on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone checks if the model has an id defined, which should naturally correspond to the backend id of the resource when using a RESTful backend.
If the `id` field on the model is set, then `save` will perform a PUT request, if not, it will generate a POST request.

Usually, the client knows the id before performing a PUT request, as it is meant to update an existing resource.
Backbone doesn't really care how you put the id. Either you can use a GET request as you indicated, or you can get the id from the DOM depending on the context. If it is the user id of the user who was currently logged in, you can also temporarily store it in the localstorage/cookie/global variable and remove it when the user logs out. This way you can avoid the extra http request.

Redirections are best done through anchor href's immediately, but if some logic has to be performed first, I also use `location.href`because this seems the best way to perform a client redirection.